# libprofiler and libtcmalloc not found even the library exist

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to build gazebo from source. When I try to build, it says that libprofiler and libtcmalloc not found. But when i check, that 2 modules already exist in /usr/lib.

Any hint for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2063/libprofiler-and-libtcmalloc-not-found-even-the-library-exist/) by [andri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/282/andri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can safely ignore those messages. libprofiler and libtcmalloc are not required packages.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0